# Парсинг данных с сайта Django

Tags: python, django, парсер

Я написал простой парсер, который с книжного сайта хватает авторов книг и загружает их в мою базу данных. Вопросы следующие:

-Куда мне его поместить (догадываюсь, в models.py)?

-Как оформить правильно? (представляю, как класс)

-Как вызывать его по нажатию кнопки в админке?

```
class Parsing:

    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page = page
        self.html_doc = urlopen(f'https://www.litmir.me/bs?rs=5%7C1%7C0&o=20&p={self.page}').read()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.html_doc)
        self.cards = self.soup.find_all('div', itemtype='http://schema.org/Book')

    def get_author(self, card):
        return card.find('span', itemprop='author').find_all('a')[0].get_text()

    def load_authors(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            Author.objects.create(f'{self.get_author(card)}')
```

Comment: 1) Куда угодно, но уж точно не в models/views/urls/admin; 2) Как угодно; 3) Добавить в админку дополнительную вьюху и в ней прописать всё что нужно https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class

Comment: Почитал на хабре, что логику лучше всего размещать в моделях. Куда еще тогда? Новый файл .ру? Он не поломает логику джанги?

Comment: Не поломает . .